# Chunking list based on struct type changing

Tags: elixir

I have a list I want to chunk up based on a transition from struct type B to A.  So for example, I have the following:

```
iex(1)> defmodule A, do: defstruct []
{:module, A ...
iex(2)> defmodule B, do: defstruct []
{:module, B ...
iex(3)> values = [ %A{}, %A{}, %B{}, %B{}, %B{}, %A{}, %A{}, %B{} ]
[%A{}, %A{}, %B{}, %B{}, %B{}, %A{}, %A{}, %B{}]
```

I want to have that data chunked up into a 2-element list containing:

```
[ [ %A{}, %A{}, %B{}, %B{}, %B{} ], [ %A{}, %A{}, %B{} ] ]
```

If the input were to be all A's or all B's initially, the output would be unchanged, since no B->A transition occurred.

I imagine `Enum.chunk_by/2` is the way to go, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to maintain the context of the previous element to know when to split.

What does an idiomatic solution to something like this look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative is to chunk_by the struct type then do another pass merging the lists (except when the list contains `%B{}`):

```
def chunk(structs) do
  structs
  |> Enum.chunk_by(& &1.__struct__)
  |> merge()
end

# Don't merge when current is %B
defp merge([[%B{}|_]=h|t]), do: [h|merge(t)]

# Merge all others
defp merge([curr, next|t]), do: [curr ++ next|merge(t)]

# We are done
defp merge([]), do: []
```

Comment: Have to pick this one as it's the only one I feel able to maintain given my current level of Elixir knowledge!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yet another approach is to use pure recursion:

```
def collect_chunks([]), do: []
def collect_chunks(list) do
  {chunk, post_chunk} = collect_chunk(list)
  [chunk | collect_chunks(post_chunk)]
end

defp collect_chunk([]), do: {[], []}
defp collect_chunk([%B{} = last_element | [%A{} | _] = post_chunk]), do: {[last_element], post_chunk}
defp collect_chunk([el | rest]) do
  {remaining_chunk, post_chunk} = collect_chunk(rest)
  {[el | remaining_chunk], post_chunk}
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`Enum.chunk_by/2` currently does not provide access to the previous element so we can not use `Enum.chunk_by/2` in this case. We will have to fallback to `reduce/3`

Of all the `Enum` functions, `reduce/3` is the most flexible and is used internally by most, if not all, of the `Enum` functions.

Below is one way to go about producing the output you want, given the values `[ %A{}, %A{}, %B{}, %B{}, %B{}, %A{}, %A{}, %B{} ]`:

```
  values
  |> Enum.reduce([[]], fn (elem, acc) ->
    prev_list = List.first(acc)         
    prev_elem = List.first(prev_list)
    b_changed_to_a? = fn -> prev_elem.__struct__ == B && elem.__struct__ == A end

    if is_nil(prev_elem) || !b_changed_to_a?.() do
      List.replace_at(acc, 0, [elem|prev_list])
    else
      [[elem]|acc]      
    end
  end)
  |> Enum.map(&Enum.reverse/1)
  |> Enum.reverse
```

Notice that I always prepend an element to a list. This is because appending to a list in Elixir is an expensive operation.

Hope this solution helps!