# Chunking a Stream with a custom chunking function

Tags: stream, elixir

I have a Stream holding an enum of two-element tuples, such as:

```
[
  {:dialogue, %{}},
  {:info, %{}},
  {:info, %{}},
  {:info, %{}},
  {:dialogue, %{}},
  {:dialogue, %{}},
  {:info, %{}}
  ...
]
```

And my end goal is to chunk the objects so that each chunk starts with a `{:dialogue, %{}}` tuple.

Originally I had code like:

```
stream
|> Stream.chunk_by(fn {type, _} -> type end) # [[dialogue], [info, info], [dialogue]...]
|> Stream.chunk(2) # [[[dialogue], [info, info, info]], [[dialogue], ...]]
```

But I soon realized that this fell down when there were two `dialogue` tuples in a row - the pair chunking no longer gave the expected outcome.

Ideally I'd like to create some method that works like:

```
chunk_when(list, fn({type, record}) -> type == :dialogue end) |> Enum.to_list
=> [[dialogue, info, info, info], [dialogue], [dialogue, info]...]
```

But I'm stuck on how to do this with the Stream module.

There must be some invocation of `Stream.transform/4` or `Stream.resource/3` that would make it work, but I can't figure it out.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280966/chunking-list-based-on-struct-type-changing) is the same idea, but it works with lists and not streams - which have a different API.

Comment: What should happen if the first tuple in the Stream is `{:info, %{}}`? Or is there an assumption the first one will always be a `{:dialogue, %{}}`?

Comment: Yep - all infos belong to the preceding dialogue, so the enum will always start with a `dialogue` tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Stream.transform/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Stream.html#transform/3) comes to the rescue:

```
defmodule A do
  @input [
    {:dialogue, %{}},
    {:info, %{}},
    {:info, %{}},
    {:info, %{}},
    {:dialogue, %{}},
    {:dialogue, %{}},
    {:info, %{}}]

  def chunk_when(input \\ @input, type \\ :dialogue) do
    input
    |> Stream.map(& &1)
    |> Stream.concat([nil])   # bah!
    |> Stream.transform([], fn e, acc ->
      case e do
        nil -> {[acc], nil}   # bah!
        {^type, _} -> {(if Enum.empty?(acc), do: [], else: [acc]), [e]}
        {_, _} -> {[], acc ++ [e]}
      end 
    end)
  end 
end

IO.inspect Enum.to_list(A.chunk_when())

#⇒ [[dialogue: %{}, info: %{}, info: %{}, info: %{}], 
#   [dialogue: %{}],
#   [dialogue: %{}, info: %{}]]
```

I am open to suggestions on how to make it more elegant in two obviously dirty places: how to not append `nil` to `input` to catch the last chunk and how to avoid stupid `if` for the very first `:dialogue` occurrence.

Comment: This only works with lists since you're doing `++ [nil]` to `input`.

Comment: @Dogbert indeed, thanks, changed `++` to `String#concat/1`, but the solution with appending dummy element to simulate `:halt` is still seems to be too hacky. Any ideas?

Comment: nice! I knew there would be a way to use Stream.transform/3 but couldn't wrap my head around how it worked, and there aren't too many examples out there in the wild.

Comment: I have already committed a [pull request to Elixir core](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/5680) to support last chunk without this dirty hack with `[nil]`, let’s see how it’d go.